multiprocessing.Queue() python method sandbox problem
multiprocessing.Queue() method of python getting "PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted" error if it is sandboxed.
CODE:
import multiprocessing

tensorflow_coordinates_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

ERROR:
./test_temp9 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/test_temp9.app/Contents/MacOS/test_temp9.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "/Applications/test_temp9.app/Contents/MacOS/multiprocessing/context.py", line 103, in Queue
  File "/Applications/test_temp9.app/Contents/MacOS/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 43, in __init__
  File "/Applications/test_temp9.app/Contents/MacOS/multiprocessing/context.py", line 68, in Lock
  File "/Applications/test_temp9.app/Contents/MacOS/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 162, in __init__
  File "/Applications/test_temp9.app/Contents/MacOS/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 57, in __init__
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

BUNDELED WITH NUITKA:
echo *** | sudo -S  python3.9 -m nuitka --run --standalone --macos-disable-console --macos-create-app-bundle --macos-app-mode=ui-element --enable-plugin=pyside6 --macos-app-icon=icons/app_icon.png --include-data-dir=icons=icons  test_temp9.py

SIGNED WITH FOLLOWING SH:
I cannot add it with the reason that it is too big.  I can send it per email if required.
ENTITLEMENTS:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
        <true/>
</dict>
</plist>

By the way, in synchronize.py", line 57 going to following line.
sl = self._semlock = _multiprocessing.SemLock(
                    kind, value, maxvalue, self._make_name(),
                    unlink_now)

I guess it is tring to reach a shared memory. there are some discussion about this SemLock method permission problems in internet but I could not find a proper solution in internet.
